# How to conditionally cache bust an API in workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

**Details about my goal.**

I have workbox webpack plugin configured to cache an API for a duration of 30 seconds. I would like to force cache bust it conditionally when a different API request is triggered.

Example, below config caches feature-flags. I am trying to cache bust it when the page sends a request to "updateTests".

**workbox configuration to cache feature-flag**
[image: workbox configuration to cache feature-flag]
**Workbox configuration updated to clear feature-flags**
[image: Workbox configuration updated to clear feature-flags]
**Cache clear makes it work**
[image]

Things I have tried

- Deleting IndexedDB manually does a fresh fetch of feature-flags

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure I understand:

- You have API calls that include the `feature-flags` in their URL, and you want all of those calls to be served cache-first out of the cache named `api`, with a 30 seconds max lifetime.
- If at any point the browser makes a request for a URL that contains `updateFlags`, that should serve as kind of a "kill switch" that automatically clears out the contents of the `api` cache, ensuring that the next `feature-flags` request will always go against the network.

Assuming that's an accurate summary, you could add a new `runtimeCaching` route to your configuration that does the following:

```
runtimeCaching: [{
  // existing route
}, {
  urlPattern: new RegExp('updateFlags'),
  handler: async ({request, event}) => {
    // Deleting the 'api' cache will ensure that the next API
    // request goes against the network.
    event.waitUntil(caches.delete('api'));

    // Assuming that you want the actual request for the URL
    // containing updateFlags to be made against the server:
    return fetch(request);
  },
}]
```

Comment: It deletes the cache but somehow it is still serving with the cached value.

Comment: If it's still serving the cached value, then that is coming from the `fetch(request)`. Which implies that the `Cache-Control` headers you're setting on your HTTP response allow for the response to come from the browser cache. You need to change those headers to disable HTTP caching.

Comment: I think that's not the issue because I have a fresh local express version that doesn't do http caching. 

I tried one more thing. After the `cache.delete('api')`, I cleared the `indexedDB` manually and it started fetching fresh from the server. I found that by reading about [deleteCacheAndMetadata](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-expiration.ExpirationPlugin#deleteCacheAndMetadata). After multiple failed attempts to invoke that function I went ahead and cleared the indexed db and it worked as expected.